# OSX How to bring Matplotlib window to the front?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib for chart visualizations, but it is very annoying to look for a window each time I run the project. Is there any way to force it to be on top of other windows? I use OSX 10.8 and PyCharm IDE and already tried

```
from pylab import get_current_fig_manager()
get_current_fig_manager().window.raise_()
```

Which fails with

```
AttributeError: 'FigureManagerMac' object has no attribute 'window'
```

I'd appreciate any other ideas.

Comment: You are trying this after using `show()`?

Answer (score 2):

you're call to window.raise_() is from PyQT.
Indeed, you can raise the window in this way but you need to:

- set PyQT4 as your backend before you do any other business with `matplotlib`

And

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
```

- Either you fix you import statement (remove the brackets) or save yourself the import and access the window through the figure

with

```
window = fig.canvas.manager.window
```

- Only then you can call `window.raise_()` and the window will be in front of pycharm.

Comment: Worked like a charm also with ```matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me from IPython:

```
from pylab import get_current_fig_manager
fm = get_current_fig_manager()
fm.show()
```

I haven't found a case in which show() doesn't work by itself, though.

Answer (score 1):

[cphlewis] had a great answer. I found myself doing this so often that I def a little function to pop all my windows up to the surface:

```
def pop_all():
    #bring all the figures hiding in the background to the foreground
    all_figures=[manager.canvas.figure for manager in matplotlib.\
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_all_fig_managers()]
    [fig.canvas.manager.show() for fig in all_figures]
    return len(all_figures)
```